# Couchbase licensing issues

Tags: couchbase, license-key

If I want to use couchbase enterprise edition, how couchbase company know whether I am using a licence version or not? Or in case I purchase a licence version couchbase enterprise edition for production environment do I need to configure licence number in production environment while installing couchbase server or not?

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a legal question than a technical question.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a legal question than a StackOverflow question, really. And I am not a lawyer.

Currently, Couchbase doesn't have a "key" that you have to enter into the Enterprise Edition to use it. However, you will have to agree to a EULA/TOS thing, and my guess is that makes you legally responsible to purchase a license to use it in production.

If you are just developing a small app, Couchbase Server Community should be adequate to get you started.